# Proper way to save and restore fragment states on backstack?

Tags: android

I have looked around and found variations of this question, but all of the answers seem to be ugly hacks. Is there no easy and proper way to achieve this?

Say for instance I have `Activity A`, which has a `FrameLayout` that can hold one fragment at a time. Lets say that when the Activity is first started it loads `Fragment A` into the `FrameLayout`, which consists of a `ListView`. When an item is selected in `Fragment A` it starts up `Fragment B`. The way I am currently doing this is by simply hiding `Fragment A` and then adding `Fragment B` since this preserves `Fragment A`'s state. I am of course also adding this fragment transaction to the `backstack`.

So now `Fragment A` exists on the `backstack`. Say now I go back to my Android home screen and go to another app. While I am doing this, the Android system decides to destroy my application because the system needs more memory. When I navigate back to my application, how am I supposed to properly restore the state of `Fragment B`, and `Fragment A` which is currently on the backstack.

I cannot use `setRetainInstance()` since it does not work for `Fragments` placed on the backstack.

Essentially what I am trying to do is restore the `backstack` to exactly how it was before my application was forcefully closed. So `Fragment A` should be on the `backstack` (but not showing), and `Fragment B` should be currently showing. If I hit the back button, it should properly pop `Fragment A` off the `backstack`.

**Some notes**

Since the application was forcefully closed, it's `savedInstanceState != null`. Same thing holds for the fragments.

Comment: I'm not sure how you're doing it, but in my app which uses Activities to single fragments I can go two to three levels deep make changes to a `TimePicker` - go to the home screen start as many apps as I want(I'm not logging so I don't know if it is ever forced to close) - navigate back and it opens in the exact state when I left. It seems to do it on its own. Maybe if you could shed some light on your tactics to get more help. Also, if you could, add links to the "hacks" you found; please.